# Display Primefaces Charts in Liferay

Tags: primefaces, charts, liferay

I'm currently trying to display a chart within a Liferay portlet. I used the following code:

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
        <h:head />
        <h:body>        

            <h1>LiferayChart</h1>
            <p:pieChart value="#{bean.model}" legendPosition="w" />
            <h1>End</h1>

        </h:body>
    </f:view>
```

And the backing bean:

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name="bean")
public class Bean {
    private PieChartModel model;

    public Bean() {
        model = new PieChartModel();
        model.set("Brand 1", 540);
        model.set("Brand 2", 325);
        model.set("Brand 3", 702);
        model.set("Brand 4", 421);
    }

    public PieChartModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }
}
```

As a result I only get an empty .

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.5 and Liferay 6.1

Does anybody know what might cause the trouble?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you try to put only one this portlet in a page ?

Comment: Yes, to keep things as simple as possible there is only this portlet deployed on the page

Comment: You try to swap `<p:pieChart` inside `<h:form`, my portlet work fine with it.

Comment: Do you see a stacktrace in the server log when the problem happens?

Comment: @RongNK: I tried to put the <p:pieChart inside a <h:form but no luck :(@Neil Griffin I also don't get any errors or warnings ...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I managed to get it working. I will probably post the exact syntax I used.